# Round to 0.5 up and down and if 0 after dot docimal

Tags: php, numbers, rounding, rating-system

Hey I have following Problems,
I get ratings and have the average of then but bow I want following:

```
1,2222222222222 = 1
1,2666666666666 = 1,5
2,3635345435435 = 2.5
2,567435 345345 = 2.5
3.5709 = 3
29,3003453450 = 29
```

I want all numbers to their most neir .5 but when they have a no decimal then should NOT be displayed 3.0 or 4.0, Just the number without decimals.

at the moment i have this code:

```
function roundRating($rating) {
    return floor($rating * 2) / 2;
}
```

can someone help me?
greets

Comment: What's up with the `3.57098 = 3.6 3 = 3`? And why do you want 29.3 rounded to 29 and not 29.5?

Comment: sorry this example was a mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion. See comments for step by step explanation.

```
<?php

$float = 1.753242342;

// Modulo operator (%) does not return float remainder. Use fmod().
$remainder = fmod($float, 1);

/* Apply rounding logic here.
 * It isn't entirely clear to me what your intended behavior is.
 * Should 0.75 round up to 1 or down to 0.5?
 * I will leave this to you to figure out.
 */
$roundedRemainder = ($remainder >= 0.25)?0.5:0;

$int = $float - $remainder;
$result = $int + $roundedRemainder;
// If remainder is zero, cast to int to remove remainder.
if (fmod($result, 1) == 0)
        $result = (int)$result;

echo "Int: " . $int . "<br>";
echo "Remainder: " . $remainder . "<br>";
echo "Rounded remainder: " . $roundedRemainder . "<br>";
echo "Result: " . $result . "<br>";
```

Outputs:

```
Int: 1
Remainder: 0.753242342
Rounded remainder: 0.5
Result: 1.5
```